# Which one is more reliable for Server sent events Firebase Realtime DB or FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

We want to send some realtime server sent events to our client apps so we decided to use Firebase cloud services. Which one is more reliable for sending realtime events Firebase Realtime DB or FCM? 
We need to make a decision because our requirement can be solved in both cases but FCM is free where as Realtime DB is paid. What are the cons If I opt for FCM over Realtime DB?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM:

- Has a very limited payload size
- Does not guarantee order of delivery

However, Realtime Database isn't guaranteed to work *at all* when the app is the the background, as the OS may kill the process and shut off everything it's doing.  FCM will wake the device and start the app upon delivery.

Comment: I am planning using firebase for sending events to client to sync up with server. In that case payload size is not an issue. The internals of FCM and realtime db are same right?

Comment: They're nothing alike.